# char inside matlab function

Tags: matlab, function

I want to run `turnMatrix(30,X)` in MATLAB. I get this error message:

> Undefined function or variable 'X'.

If I change `X` to 1 it is successful. My code is below.

```
function turnMatrix(d,b)

a = d * pi / 180 ;

if b == X %  1
    R = [1 0 0 0 ; 0 cos(a) -sin(a) 0 ; 0 sin(a) cos(a) 0 ; 0 0 0 1];

elseif b == Y % 2
    R = [cos(a) 0 sin(a) 0 ; 0 1 0 0 ; -sin(a) 0 cos(a) 0 ; 0 0 0 1];

elseif b == Z % 3
    R = [1 0 0 0 ; 0 cos(a) -sin(a) 0 ; 0 sin(a) cos(a) 0 ; 0 0 0 1];
end

R

end
```

Comment: Inside the function, `X` is unknown. You pass the value of `X` into the function, but there it is known as `b` (2nd input argument). Once you fix `X`, you’ll have problems with `Y` and `Z` as well.

Comment: 2nd input argument should be char.

Comment: thank you for change my typo.

Comment: You still didn't define X, Y and Z. So it is instruction in style "Check if b is equal unknowns value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are really expecting/wanting to specify the second input as a characters/string, that is

```
turnMatrix(30,'X')
```

Note the single quotes around `'X'`, which say that it is literally the character string `'X'`, not the value of the variable `X`.

Then inside the function you need

```
if b == 'X'

elseif b == 'Y'

elseif b == 'Z'

end
```

That is, compare the value of variable `b` to the character `'X'`.  The way you have it, you are trying to compare the value of variable `b` to the value of variable `X`, but variable X doesn't exist and hence the error.

Note also, that if you were comparing anything other than a single character (and even in the single character case) you'd be better off using a switch-case construct rather than if-else

```
switch b
   case 'X'

   case 'Y'

   case 'Z'

end
```